# Recompile all Python files in directory

Tags: python, compiler-construction

I have a Python directory with a number of .py files. I recently compiled them into .pyc files using `python -m compileall`. I have now changed some of the source files and would like to recompile, writing over the old .pyc files.

Is there a quick way to do this from the command line without having to manually delete all existing .pyc files?

Answer (score 9):

You just have to run `python -m compileall` again. It will overwrite older .pyc files. You can pass it the `-f` switch to force rebuild even if timestamps are up to date (as per [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/compileall.html)).

Answer (score 4):

When the source code has changed, new .pyc files are automatically created when you run the program again. Therefore I wouldn't worry about compiling, but focus your attention on the code itself.. :)

Comment: There is a use case for this. Quoting the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/compileall.html): "This module can be used to create the cached byte-code files at library installation time, which makes them available for use even by users who don’t have write permission to the library directories."

Comment: @PauloAlmeida - Ah, that is indeed the a use case which could make sense. In that case indeed: just rerun `python -m compileall`